# How to filter JSON array into PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, filter

I have a JSONArray generated in java and I post it to one of my PHP files where it's saved to a file. From there it gets read and I need to generate a chart based on this data. All I need is to convert my raw JSON which has values I don't need, into a simply php array.

```
[{"id":1,"timestamp":"1363135091","reward":1200,"player":"Orangeguy24","address":"108.28.239.167","service":"MC-Index"},{"id":2,"timestamp":"1363135091","reward":1200,"player":"Orangeguy24","address":"108.28.239.167","service":"MC-Index"}]
```

Is an example of 2 elements inside my JSON array. What I need todo is filter those values into arrays accordingly.

For example get how many votes a 'player' has,  I need to add up how ever many elements are in the JSONArray, because 1 element is 1 vote (the id is primary auto-increment in my mysql DB, not located on my webserver)

I'd like the array to be to [player, votes] so when I echo the array it will be easily parsed by the google chart tools I'm using. I've spent the last 5 hours working on this and I've been stuck, thanks for any help!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) json_decode, for starters?

Comment: `<?php 
$string = file_get_contents("../json/voting.txt");
$json = json_decode($string);
echo $string;
?>` I'm parsing http://milkycraft.net/json/voting.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To decode the JSON into a php array, you can do:

```
$json_array = json_decode($raw_json);
```

Then, to get the number of votes for each player out of the array:

```
$player_votes = array_reduce($json_array,
    function($v, $item) {
        if(!array_key_exists($item->player, $v))
            $v[$item->player] = 1;
        else
            $v[$item->player] = 1 + $v[$item->player];

        return $v;
    }, array());
```

If I understand your question correctly, this will work.

EDIT: Updated the second code snippet

Comment: Vardump produces: array(1) { [""]=> int(337) }

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$str   = '[{"id":1,"timestamp":"1363135091","reward":1200,"player":"Orangeguy24","address":"108.28.239.167","service":"MC-Index"},{"id":2,"timestamp":"1363135091","reward":1200,"player":"Orangeguy24","address":"108.28.239.167","service":"MC-Index"}]';

$res   = array();
foreach(json_decode($str,true) as $val){
  if(array_key_exists($val['player'],$res)){
     $res[$val['player']]   = $res[$val['player']]+1;
  }
  else{
     $res[$val['player']]   = 1;
  }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [Orangeguy24] => 2
)
```

Comment: Thanks works well after I strtolower'd the entire json string, now I just need to figure how to get the array back into a format that google charts likes, it's pretty picky.