# How to use php to count the same array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I read a few of the threads but none of them seem to match what I need.
What I'm trying to do it something like a voting system but does not include mysql at the moment.

I made three radio buttons of music types pop, rock, metallic and a submit
so whichever a person choose either one of them and submit the data is wrote into a data.json and stored there.

Then I have a page to load all the data in data.json file but I want to count how many people selected for example metallic and how many people selected rock.

At the moment I'm still testing and I actually thought of an idea but somehow searched up and not getting what I want.....can someone give me a hand?

This is my data.json file

```
{"type":"metallic"}
{"type":"pop"}
{"type":"metallic"}
```

and this is what my result code is at the moment

```
<?php
$file = fopen('data.json', "r");       

$array_record = array();

while(!feof($file))                       
{
    $line = fgets($file);                 
    $data = json_decode($line, TRUE);     

    if (is_array($data))                  
    {                
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) 
        {
           // echo $key.'='.$value.' ';      // show key=value pairs
          $array_record += array($value,);
          var_dump($data);
          print_r($data);
          echo $value;

        }
        echo '<br>'.PHP_EOL;             
    }
}


fclose($file);                          
?>
```

I know the codes are messy because I tried setting up an empty array first then get the `$value` which is something like metallic into an array so I can use the array_count_values but the way I'm doing it seems totally wrong or that'd never work.  I tried few other ways to get only metallic/pop so I can try counting the same thing.

AH! I just found this topic [How to filter JSON array into PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489307/how-to-filter-json-array-into-php-array)

I'm going to read this thread tomorrow and see if it helps.
But it wouldn't hurt if you can give me a hand too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Keep in mind the JSON you have posted is a not a valid JSON.](http://jsonlint.com/)

[**`array_reduce`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
<?php
$json = '[{"type":"metallic"},{"type":"pop"},{"type":"metallic"}]';
$result = array_reduce(json_decode($json,TRUE),
    function($v, $item)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($item['type'], $v))
            $v[$item['type']] = 1;
        else
            $v[$item['type']]++;
        return $v;
    }, array()
);
print_r($result);
```

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/49726)

Comment: Totally new with json but after you told me that it's invalid I searched around and I know what you meant but weird I am using json_encode to store into the data.json file and what I pasted is what's stored in the data.json and the decode does read the data though.

Comment: thanks for the info, not exactly understanding it fully esp. the $v[$item['type']] part but I'll do some more researches~!

Comment: @user2128405 `$v` is the callback result, so what is passed back to `$result` is `$v` and `$v[$item['type']]` means we are making the key of each `$v` the value or `$item['type']`, in your case `metallic` and `php` and the value a number that increased every time the same type is found. [Its also detailed here.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

Comment: ah, thanks I believe I know what you mean now and reading it slowly and carefully.

Comment: this is how I coded my file to be encoded into json.
json_encode($_POST).PHP_EOL
which is why it's different from what you showed me but if I open up my json and use it with the array_reduce it wouldn't work though

Comment: @user2128405 you did that on a foreach? or on the `$_POST` directly? does it give an similar one if u do `json_encode(array($_POST)).PHP_EOL`

Comment: I didn't do it on a foreach this is what I did...
inside if statement I used
`fwrite($file_handle,json_encode)($_POST).PHP_EOL);`

Comment: if I use your way which is 'json_encode(array($_POST)).PHP_EOL' then my result in my data.json is 
[{"type":"metallic"}]
[{"type":"rock"}]
[{"type":"pop"}]

Comment: @user2128405 are you not using `type[]` on the form?

Comment: this is what I used for my form...
`foreach($music_type as $type)
{
 echo $type . '<input type="radio" name="type" value='. $type . '>' . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
}`

Comment: `name="type[]"` will return an array, using radio button it should return you a single item. That's why you get a single `[{"type":"metallic"}]`. You would need to use `name="type[]"` with `checkbox` instead of `radio` button

Comment: ah ok....I'm not trying that out yet since I'm still trying to figure something else out :( hate it when I get stuck and then brain would just keep on stuck even with the easiest thing.  I will totally keep that in mind and play around with it after I'm done trying to do what I'm trying now.